# passing data in jQuery get method

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass in some data as parameters in jquery method but it seems to be not working.

```
  $.get('/quizes', { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    renderQuiz(data)
  });
```

However, on my express route, when I am looking for the data in req.body, it is showing undefined. What am I missing?

Comment: There is no body for a Get. The params are serialized into url query string `path/to/server?name=John&time=2pm`. If you want to keep same body code switch to POST

Answer (score 3):

Those parameters are not in req.body they are in `req.query`.